# Inject Gradle properties into Spring Boot application.yml, not working in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I've managed to inject the Gradle proj.ver into application.yml and after that injected it into service application. 
My **application.yml** looks like this:

```
project: 
  version: ${version}
```

But it works only if I started the app from cli with:

```
gradle bootRun
```

If I'm trying to start the app from **IntelliJ**, it didn't work and it failed with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'version' in value "${version}"
```

I read all the answers from Stackoverflow and they suggested two solutions:

1. Use spring profiles
2. Modify run configuration and run before launch the gradle task: **processResources**

I'd prefer something like a ***default*** value for proj.ver when I'm running from IntelliJ. Is that possible? Or are any better solutions for this situation ?
Thanks

Comment: `${version:default}` should give you a default if not found.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but as I wrote in the answer it seems that only like this work from both sides: `${version?:unknown}`

Comment: That shouldn't be needed as it is a value expression and not a SpEL expression. Unless this is somehow parsed by gradle (which it probably is) which does the replacement.

Comment: can you say how you inject gradle properties into application.yaml?

Comment: Yes of course, I've updated the response. You can find out the steps there. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As M. Deinum said above in the comment, I managed to run the app from IntelliJ, but now the `gradle bootRun` started to fail with:

> Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: unknown for class: SimpleTemplateScript2

After some more research it seems that `${version?:unknown}`(**with the question mark**) it works either from the IDE or from cli.

---

I've updated the response, in order for others to know how to inject Gradle build info into Spring-boot:

1) Tell Gradle to pass the build data towards a Spring yml file like this:

```
processResources {
filesMatching('appInfo.yml') {
    expand(project.properties)
}}
```

2) The appInfo.yml will look like:

```
project:
  version: ${version?:unknown}
```

3) Inject the version of the build into Spring services like:

```
@Value("${project.version}")
private String applicationVersion;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete for Kotlin user, what works for me was :

1. build.gradle.kts

   ```
    tasks.processResources { filesMatching("**/application.properties") { expand(project.properties) } }
   ```
2. application.properties

   ```
    project.version= ${version}
   ```
3. Service.kt

   ```
    @Value("\${project.version}") lateinit var version: String
   ```